# 64GB MacBook Pro using Swap space

Tags: memory, virtual-memory

Any idea why my computer is using swap?

[image]

Comment: Because at some point since last reboot you used sufficient memory to warrant it.

Comment: run activity monitor when you use your computer and watch memory usage.

Comment: It has never hit 64GB. I'm consistently in the 30-40GB range but I still have 8GB of swap used. The longer I leave it on the more swap that builds up